# Sitecore Wrong Route in MVC

Tags: model-view-controller, sitecore, sitecore7, sitecore7.5

I updated sitecore 7.0 to 7.5 and there are some controller rendering items created by MVC3.

When I execute them in 7.5, it shows an error:

> Could not create controller: 'Components'. The current route url is: 'api/sitecore/{controller}/{action}'.
>   `Message: The controller for path '/api/sitecore/Components/Navigation' was not found or does not implement IController.

The name of controller is `Components` and action is `Navigation`

I worked perfectly in Sitecore 7.0.
How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Do you have a controller called `ComponentsController` and does it inherit from `Controller`?

Comment: No, I don't have. I'm calling post request by using ajax by passing `@Url.Action("Navigation", "Components")`

Comment: I don't know if it's relevant but Sitecore 7.5 does not support MVC3. It requires MVC 5.1 (see compatibility table https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/087164 ). Also you may need to follow the convention and rename your component to `ComponentsController` (while still using `/api/sitecore/components/navigation` path).

Comment: @MarekMusielak I already checked the compatibility table and I guess you can use MVC3 version in higher version if you don't use any new features being available in MVC4 or MVC5. Is it right?

Comment: @MarekMusielak I need to add that I refer only `Sitecore.Mvc` from its bin folder.

Comment: Have you tried to rename your controller class to `ComponentsController`?

Comment: @MarekMusielak I will try. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, try to append "Controller" into your "components"  like "componentsController" and you can also disable CommandRoutePrefix at `Sitecore.Speak.Mvc.config` file in `/App_Config/Includes/`

Also, if you want to pass value into specific location, you can use static url instead of `@Url.Action(...)`